# Magento custom URL Rewrite always matches category page after re-index

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url, url-rewriting

I have a blog MODULE installed on my Magento and it's URL is /blog.

I have a Blog CATEGORY in the nav bar with the URL /blog-away.html

I tried the URL Custom Rewrite and it works, until you re-index the site, then it reverts back to the category URL of /blog-away.html. I want the category to stay redirected to /blog.

Observations:

1. the blog module does not use table "core_url_rewrite" - a least I didn't find any evidence.
2. if the category and blog URLs are the same ("blog.html") - Magento routing will always first match the category and open the category page, you will never get the blog page.
3. if the category has URL "blog.html" and the blog has, like, "wine-blog.html", you can't create a custom redirect from "blog.html" to "wine-blog.html".  Magento will throw an error: "Request Path for Specified Store already exists." (the category's request_path is "blog.html")

So, given all that, I think it may work by setting up a redirect in the shop's root .htaccess file. But I've no clue what code to put in.

Comment: Hi, 1) Do .htaccess redirection for this, there is no other way for this, if you use category url rewrite management it will always create the same problame. 2) Otherwise call that blog module initial controller from url and hard code that url in you category navigation section

Comment: Hello @DasarathiSwain,
I am trying to rewrite via .htaccess with :

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^OLD-URL-TO-REDIRECT?$ NEW-URL-WHERE-YOU-WANT-TO-REDIRECT-THE-OLD-ONE [R=301,L]

But it is not working. Do you have any suggestions as to the proper way to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

From your question I guess you have edited you `URL Rewrite` like this

```
Request Path: blog.html
Target Path: blog
```

Please follow this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar) to create a new custom `URL Rewrite` with

```
Request Path: blog
Target Path: catalog/category/view/id/{blog category id}
```

And keep original URL Rewrite of Blog category as it is.  Then since our custom `URL Rewrite` path is dependent on actual Category target path so `Re-indexing` won't effect it.

Answer (score 0):

In

> system->configuration->catalog

search for `search engine optimizations`

Edit product URL suffix and category URL suffix fields, replace `.html` to any other value or remove it.

Or use optimise web extension.